# Django get_FOO_display in a list

Tags: django

I've got a model Technique with a CharField procedure with Choices.

I've got a list with groups of varying numbers of these choices:

```
procs = [['CS'],['C1','C2','ID'],['C1','C2','C3','C4'],
    ['ID'],['RP'],['GY']]
```

(e.g. 'CS' is Cheese etc)

I'm trying get an output such as
['Cheese'], 2
['Chips','Nuts'], 0
etc

```
for proc in procs:
    proc_tot = Technique.objects.filter(
        date__range=[d1,d2]).filter(procedure__in=proc).count()
    m=[]
    for k in proc:
        k = Technique(procedure=proc)
        m.append(str(k.get_procedure_display()))
    m, proc_tot
```

But the get_FOO_display() is throwing a TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Why is this, and is there a better way to get to the same output ?

Thanks

Comment: You might simplify it with aggregation features - what is `total`? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it's a previous filter. I've edited it to show that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `proc` is a list, and `procedure` field need a string.

You need to extract the first element, to get the string and then you can assign it.

Also, you are iterating over `proc` using `k`, but then you are re-assigning it. That does not make sense. May be you want something like that

```
for k in proc:
    technique = Technique(procedure=k)
    m.append(str(technique.get_procedure_display()))
```